# PHP Merge arrays and add a value

Tags: php, arrays

I need help merging two PHP arrays:

Array 1:

```
Array
(
[0] => 2
[1] => 3
[2] => 4
[3] => 6
)
```

Array 2:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id_sabor] => 2
        [chocolate] => N
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id_sabor] => 3
        [chocolate] => S
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id_sabor] => 4
        [chocolate] => N
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id_sabor] => 5
        [chocolate] => S
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id_sabor] => 6
        [chocolate] => N
    )

)
```

The values on array 1 are the active objects. I need to keep on Array 2 or on a new array only the ones with an `[id_sabor]` that matches in the array 1 (in this case: `2, 3, 4` and `6`). Also, on those that `[chocolate]=S` add a new value: `[costo_extra]=25`.

Comment: Just a loop over array 2 and some `if`s.

Comment: What are you trying to create? The second array has both the number and the chocolate letter. What is the expected output supposed to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do that could be to use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) and use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check if the first array contains the value of `id_sabor`.

```
$array1 = [2, 3, 4, 6];
$array2 = [
    ["id_sabor" => 1, "chocolate" => "N"],
    ["id_sabor" => 2, "chocolate" => "N"],
    ["id_sabor" => 3, "chocolate" => "S"],
    ["id_sabor" => 4, "chocolate" => "N"],
    ["id_sabor" => 5, "chocolate" => "S"],
    ["id_sabor" => 6, "chocolate" => "N"]
];

$array2 = array_reduce($array2, function($carry, $item) use ($array1){
    if (in_array($item["id_sabor"], $array1)) {
        if ($item["chocolate"] === "S") {
            $item["costo_extra"] = 25;
        }
        $carry[] = $item;
    }
    return $carry;
});
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/V5sFH)

Comment: Thank you very much, The forth bird. It´s exactly what I need :)